# Hide some posts in Jekyll, but allow their content to be included elsewhere

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am using [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) to generate a static website. I currently display posts by category on their own pages using some simple liquid syntax:

```
{%- for post in site.categories.whatever -%}
    {{ post.content }}
{%- endfor -%}
```

However, the posts are still generated independently (in `/category/year/month/day/title.html` per the Jekyll defaults), which I don't need.

How can I prevent each post from generating its own independent HTML page while still being able to loop over `site.categories` and include them in a page with multiple posts? Setting `published: false` unfortunately prevents the posts from being added to `site.categories`, which breaks the above `for` loop. `permalink: none` also has no apparent effect. Excluding the pages (via `exclude: [xyzzy, plugh, ...]` in `_config.yml`) does the same. A [previous StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126829/is-it-possible-to-stop-jekyll-from-generating-a-page-for-each-post) suggested setting the permalink to an existing page, but in Jekyll 3.6.2 this simply overwrites that page.

My current hack is to set the permalink for that category to `/.trash` which is then easy to ignore when uploading the published site, but it seems like there ought to be a better way.

Comment: You could use another collection with output false, or does that not work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'd like to have some of the other benefits posts offer :/ But you're right, a collection would be one alternative.

Comment: Specifically, collections currently [can't use Liquid](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/6211), and it's easier to generate RSS from posts.

Comment: I have build dozens of Jekyll sites and not experienced these limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that simply setting the permalink to the empty string (mostly) works! With

```
defaults:
  - scope:
        path:       category/_posts
    values:
        permalink:  ''
```

in your `_config.yml`, none of those posts will have a generated page.

Unfortunately, the pages are still included in `site.documents` and similar pages, but at least it suppresses the output. I sadly think that it's not possible to exclude these from `site.documents`, but it's easy enough to avoid them in Liquid.